# Scripting environment setup

Tags: software-recommendation, development, applescript, script, developer-program

When I start a session programming on my macbook pro, I have a bunch of apps I'd like open and ready:

- DevNull smtp java server (run from terminal with `java -jar DevNull.jar`)
- Terminal shell in the tomcat/bin directory with `startup.sh;tail -f ../logs/catalina.out` running after `rm -rf` work and test webapp directories
- IntelliJ running
- after tomcat loads (fine with just having a timer), Firefox with my webapp loaded
- after tomcat loads, Chrome with my webapp loaded
- ForkLift
- TextMate
- Couple of Finder windows open in particular directories

Those are pretty core...  then it depends on what exactly I'm working on as far as other apps I need open.

So how do I write a script I can double click on and have all the above ready for me, saving me a couple minutes each day and being a little less annoying getting started?  Is there a nice app that can easily do the above for me?  Do I need to write a bash or python script for this? Or learn applescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a bash script for this as everything that you list can be opened in bash.  Use the `open` command pointing to the application to run the application or a folder location to open a particular folder with finder.

Comment: sounds easy, what about loading firefox or chrome only after tomcat has fully loaded?  Is there an easy way to do this?  Could I run `tail -f` on catalina.out, pipe it to grep for the startup line and then load chrome and firefox somehow?

Comment: I would just use the bash sleep command in the script to pause the script for a short period whilst tomcat loads.  A lot simpler.  See http://ss64.com/bash/sleep.html

I would load Chrome and Firefox last in the script, so the sleep time should be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I use Concentrate to load up apps relevant to whatever I'm doing right now - you can run terminal commands, Applescripts, load programs, etc. I hit 'concentrate', make some tea, and then return to everything running. I know I could do this with Automator, but I'm too lazy to learn how.